# check if same option has been selected more than once in group of select elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamic number of select elements, and when the form is submitted I want to check if the same option has been selected more than once with JQuery. If it has then show an error. Any ideas?

```
<div class="container-seller-commission">
            <div class="row-seller-commission">
                <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" selected="selected">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option></select>
              </div>

            </div>
        <div class="row-seller-commission">
             <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option></select>
            </div>
    <div class="row-seller-commission">

                <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Owner</option>
    <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Support</option></select>

            </div></div>
```

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be uniuqe__

Comment: What type of error. What does the error say? Is it the markup error due to same ID's or a JavaScript error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, get the values of all selects into an array, determine if all the items in the array are unique

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var items = $('.select-seller').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
  
  console.log(isUnique(items));
});

function isUnique(arr){
   var uniqueValues = arr.reduce(function(p,c){
     if(p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
     return p;
    },[]);
  
  return uniqueValues.length == arr.length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-seller-commission">
            <div class="row-seller-commission">
                <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" selected="selected">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option></select>
              </div>

            </div>
        <div class="row-seller-commission">
             <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option></select>
            </div>
    <div class="row-seller-commission">

                <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid"><option value=""></option><option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Owner</option>
    <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Support</option></select>

            </div></div>

<button>test</button>
```

Do make sure you give your html elements unique id's!